# Loading pictures with code

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub frmPegSolitaire_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each pictire As PictureBox In Me.Controls
        If Not pictire.Tag.Equals("n") Then
            pictire.Image = Image.FromFile("peg.png")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Here is my code that does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please clarify *"does not work"*; give a [mcve].

Comment: "does not work" is not a very good problem description. _What_ isn't working, and what is currently happening when you run it?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Question1.exe

Comment: Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox'.

Comment: The exception is probably due to `For Each pictire As PictureBox In Me.Controls`.  There is no guarantee that every control in the controls collection is going to be a `PictureBox`.

Comment: i do have only one label but why it is not loading the code. i have to load 49 picture boxes with different pictures in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping over all the Controls contained in `Me` (probably the Form)
In that collection there is more than just the PictureBoxes so you need to filter to only get those :
*(see [OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx))*

```
Private Sub frmPegSolitaire_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each pictire As PictureBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)
        If Not pictire.Tag.Equals("n") Then
            pictire.Image = Image.FromFile("peg.png")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You were faster than me. :)

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Question1.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @vkaleri you have something whose value is `Nothing` somewhere in your code ; my bet would be some pictureboxes' `Tag` aren't set (and so have `Nothing` as value) ; either add a check or give a value to all